# Qt Regular Expressions assistance required

Tags: regex, qt, text, pattern-matching

I'm trying to construct a regular expression to retreive file types from a strictly formatted string.  The format is along the lines of

`"Image formats (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"`

My first theory was to search for strings beginning with '*' then '.' then match (and capture) any character until it found a space or round bracket such as.

`QRegExp re("\\*\\.(.*)[\\s|\\)]")`

Which gives me the following (with minimal enabled)

`"*.png"` and `"png"`

I have also tried using the \w (word character) but to no prevail. The Regular expression engine uses perl syntax and backslashes also need to be 'escaped' since c++ also processes them.

Question:

I need a regular expression to search for file types from a strictly formatted string, i.e from the string above I would need 3 strings "png", "jpg" and "bmp".

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Your regex seems fine. It might be an issue related to scope. Make sure if your regex has a global scope. Generally it is done by adding a /g at the end of regex, not so sure about perl syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QString str = "Image formats (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)";
QRegExp re("([*][.](.*))[\\s|\\)]"); // "(\\*\\.(.*))[\\s|\\)]" - also works
re.setMinimal(true);

int pos = 0;
while ((pos = re.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1)
{
    qDebug() << re.cap(1) << re.cap(2);
    pos += re.matchedLength();
}
```

Output:

```
"*.png" "png"
"*.jpg" "jpg"
"*.bmp" "bmp"
```